# Delphi XE2 idHttpServer BASIC Authentication

Tags: authentication, http-headers, delphi-xe2, indy10

I Have a idHttpServer server that works fine and i put a basic authentication like this :

```
procedure TfrmMain.IdHTTPServer1CommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
Var
     Cmd           : String;
     Retorno       : string;
begin
     Cmd := ARequestInfo.RawHTTPCommand;

     if  Not ((ARequestInfo.AuthUsername = 'user') and
              (ARequestInfo.AuthPassword = 'pass'))
     Then Begin
         AResponseInfo.AuthRealm := 'Forneça autenticação';
         AResponseInfo.WriteContent;
         Exit;
     End;

     // Do the Work
     // ....
End;
```

It´s ok, It works normally, if the user in the browser does not provide the authentication the browser asks the user and the password. Ok !

Once the user provided the password and the server did the work, at a next request, the server does not return the denied authentication to be requested again because it considers that it has already been provided in the previous requisition, that is

```
ARequestInfo.AuthUsername  And ARequestInfo.AuthPassword
```

are always pre-filled in the next requisitions without the browser asking them for the user.

If I quit the browser and start again proceed another request, it continues without asking for authentication.

Is there any way to make the browser always ask for authentication on all requests?

Comment: FYI, you don't need to call `WriteContent` directly, just `Exit` and let `TIdHTTPServer` send the response for you.

Comment: The browser can cache the credentials based on URL and reuse them for subsequent requests to that URL. Most browsers provide that feature, the user decides whether to enable it. The only way to force the browser to re-authenticate is to send a new `401` reply, but you should not do that if it will diminish the user's experience. `TIdHTTPServer` does not cache `AuthUsername`/`AuthPassword`, they are re-parsed on each request, so the browser must be re-sending them. Why do you care if the browser re-authenticates each request? As long as your server receives the correct credentials, all is OK.

Comment: If that is not what you want, then you will have to switch from HTTP-based authentication to HTML-based authentication, where the user has to login to an HTML webform that is submitted to the server, and then the server returns a session cookie that has to be sent back to the server in subsequent requests. If the user logs out, invalidate the cookie. If the user closes the browser, the browser will destroy the cookie automatically. If a request to something other than the HTML login page is missing a valid cookie, redirect (via `AResponseInfo.Redirect()`) to the login page.

Comment: Got it, I need it to always authenticate because multiple users can use the same machine and each one has their user and password

Comment: To do that with HTTP authentication, you would have to send a `401` reply after every successful `200` reply. That is not very efficient, and causes a lot of back-and-forth that eats up network traffic (and SSL/TLS overhead if you use HTTPS), and it is just not a good user experience in general. I would switch to HTML authentication instead. If a new user needs to use the same machine, have the previous user logout first. And then let a logged in user send as many requests as they need without logging in multiple times.

Comment: Remy, I was unable to resend the 401 response because either the server sends 200 or 401. I did not understand how to do this. Can you explain or put the code that do it for me?

Comment: You already know how to send `401` (setting an `AuthRealm` automatically sends a `401`). You will have to keep track in your own code when to send `401` vs `200`. For instance, enable the `TIdHTTPServer.SessionState` property so you can then use the `ARequestInfo.Session` and `AResponseInfo.Session` properties to carry data between requests. Define a flag that your code can use to know which response to send.  In `OnCommand...`, if `ARequestInfo.Session` is missing the flag, send `401` and set the flag, otherwise send `200` and clear the flag.

Comment: Got it. thank you so much !!

Comment: I can not use Session, ARequestInfo.Session is always set to nil in IdHTTPServer1CommandGet even setting StateSession and AutoStartSession to true in idHttpServer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138763/discussion-between-claudio-ferreira-and-remy-lebeau).